# Посоветуйте WiFi точку доступа

Tags: wifi, железо

Хочу дома заменить исторически появившуюся сборную солянку из различных DLink/TP-Link.

Что хочу от точки доступа:

- Только точка доступа. Роутер не нужен. Наличие дополнительных ethernet портов будет плюсом, но в целом неважно.
- PoE будет плюсом, но в целом тоже неважно.
- Двухдиапазонная. bgn/ac
- Должна стабильно работать 24/7
- Возможность автоматизации конфигурирования. У меня дома большая часть железа конфигурируется при помощи ansible. В целом можно даже без web-интерфейса, но думаю такого оборудования уже давно нет.
- Возможность снятия подробной статистики. Хочется видеть что творится с точками. Сколько клиентов на какой, уровни сигналов, распределение по каналам и так далее. Дома развернут prometheus + grafana

Comment: К Убикьюти присмотрись. У друга в деревне на фонарном столбе 2 точки делают вайфай мост уже пару лет как. На счёт ансибла - хз, но какой-то шелл должен быть.

Comment: Убики у меня на позапрошлой работе были. Не совсем то, вдобавок хотят себе в сети контроллер, а контроллер писан на java

Comment: У нас на работе D-Link - вроде пашут. Могу у того кто ими занимается подробнее узнать.

Comment: Ну, dlink'и у меня есть. Приходится всётаки вокруг них танцевать с установкой *wrt, чтобы появлялась возможность как то более-менее удобно ими управлять. А хотелось бы без танцев - просто при необходимости покупать еще одну точку, прописывать ей ip в dhcp и в инвентаре и выкатывать конфигурацию сразу.

Comment: Ну у длинков есть `snmp`, но он меня оч сильно напугал. Технически - можно втащить конфиг.

Comment: Юбики как точки доступа хорошо управляются своим софтовым контроллером. настроить её также можно через конфиг по ssh, но манов нигде нет - работай наугад. snmp вроде есть.

Comment: Убики у меня были. Управлялка у них хорошая, но это больше нужно для предприятия типа гостиницы. А мне дома неохота эту жавовую управлялку запущенной держать. Да и точек от силы пять будет. Идеально - чтобы можно было ансиблом точки настроить и пусть работают.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После долгого но неспешного вкуривания различных моделей остановился всё-таки на [MikroTik hAP ac²](https://mikrotik.com/product/hap_ac2)

- Уговорил себя, что маленький свич в кадой точке не помешает
- PoE in в наличии, равно как и питание от БП
- 802.11b/g/n + 802.11a/n/ac
- Пока нареканий нет
- Ansible [умеет в RouterOS](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/user_guide/platform_routeros.html), хотя и сделано спустя рукава
- Есть готовый [экспортер статистики в прометей](https://github.com/nshttpd/mikrotik-exporter)

В целом хорошо. Вот только ansible подкачал. Боюсь всё выльется в написании собственного модуля, хотя в принципе и с существующим жить можно.